# Comment link from one answer of a question to another answer on the same question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, self-promotion

I often see comments on a highly rated or accepted answer that looks something like

> For an awesome solution to this problem see `http://stackoverflow.com/a/blah/blah`

Then when I click on the link, it brings me to another answer on the same page / question

> Here's my buggy downvoted answer:
>
> Blah blah blah blah

If this user's solution was really that good, would he have to self promote? Wouldn't his answer just be ranked higher?

Should these type of comments be flagged as not constructive? Should they be flagged at all?

Comment: Those types of answers should be flagged as spam too... Unless that's some type of over-generalization.

Comment: Even if "my" is removed, both are link-only answers and should be flagged. However, partial answers are acceptable on SO, so linking between answers should not be removed. If a new answer builds upon an existing one, it is acceptable to add the link.

Comment: Forget linking to another website/blog, I guess I take issue with people blatantly promoting their answers, especially when their answer just isn't that good.

Answer (score 2):

> If the user's solution was really that good, would he have to self promote? Wouldn't his answer would just be ranked higher?

Yep, so just flag the comment. Whether the linked answer is actually good or not, there is no need for such self-promotion. And with enough flags it would be removed.

I don't see a practical way to prevent such links altogether, without some undesirable side-effects. A flag will suffice, I'd say.